# GitHub private - collaborator cannot access the repository

Tags: github, repository, github-enterprise, github-organizations

One of our users create a private repository within and organisation on GitHub Enterprise. He added a collaborator, but this person get 404 error when trying to access the repo. I added my account to this repo and all works fine for me.

Added collaborator is in the same organisation, repo is visible on his profile, link to repo is fine too (it works for me and repo owner).

I was searching the answer in Internet, but no luck.

Do you have any idea, what can cause this situation?

Comment: Did the person try logging out and back in again? Seems like an issue for GitHub support to me

Comment: Yes, he did. Thanks @AdilB!

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because the user who is having an issue's client isn't properly authenticating.
You can read more about it here: https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/

Comment: thanks! This is what I was searching for. I will check if it works for this user. :)